# How can this be re-written with the following identity?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Can this: 
$$\frac{\cos x}{4 + \sin^2 x}$$

Be re-written using the fact that: 
$$\cot(t) = \frac{\cos (t)}{\sin (t)} = \frac{1}{\tan (t)}$$

I'm not good with algebra, but I'm getting there. I'm trying to simplify this expression, it's an integration by substitution task. I just don't see how I can separate $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ from the original equation.

Comment: If it's integration by substitution, you should substitute $u=\sin x$. You don't need $\cot$.

Comment: That would give me; 1/(4+u^2) which I still can't integrate. :(

Comment: [Are you sure about that?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Derivatives_of_inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Comment: Evil ponnies! The 1/a^2+x^2 rule! Thanks. If you put that in a reply I'll give you the creds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{4 + \sin^2 x} dx = \int \frac{1}{4 + u^2} du \; .$$

Substituting $u=\sin x$.

The result is

$$\int \frac{1}{4 + u^2} du = \int \frac{1}{2(1 + (u/2)^2)} d(u/2)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)+c \; .$$

Substituting back $u=\sin x$ we get the final result:

$$\int \frac{\cos x}{4 + \sin^2 x} dx = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{\sin x}{2}\right)+c \; .$$